# GCP Bigtable client with Vert.X blocking out

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, vert.x, google-cloud-bigtable

I am using Vert.X and Bigtable client library provided by GCP. The call for querying data is made from a worker pool/executeBlocking. But the AsyncResult which i receive is null and after a while warning logs gets printed for the worked thread being blocked for too long.

Gradle Dependencies:

```
object Versions {
  const val protobuf = "3.20.1"
  const val bigtable = "2.5.3"
}

dependencies {
  apply(plugin = "io.freefair.lombok")

  implementation("com.google.protobuf", "protobuf-java", Versions.protobuf)
  implementation("com.google.cloud", "google-cloud-bigtable", Versions.bigtable)
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind
  implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.0")
  compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok")
  annotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok")
  implementation(platform("io.vertx:vertx-stack-depchain:$vertxVersion"))
  implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.+")
  implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.+")
  implementation("io.vertx:vertx-config")
  implementation("io.vertx:vertx-web")
  implementation("io.vertx:vertx-micrometer-metrics")
  implementation("io.vertx:vertx-opentracing")
  testImplementation("io.vertx:vertx-junit5")
  testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:$junitJupiterVersion")
}
```

> Bigtable API call:

```
vertx.<Row>executeBlocking(t->{
      var row=dataClient.readRow(TABLE_ID,"1234#DATA");
      t.complete(row);
    }).onComplete(r->{
      log.info("Result"+r.result());
    });
```

Below are the logs:
11:36:46.376 [vert.x-worker-thread-1] INFO  StateRepository - StateRepository being deployed

11:36:46.379 [vert.x-worker-thread-1] INFO  StateRepository - Resultnull

I am thinking that Bigtable client creates an executor internally to handle the connection and is not using the worked thread pool under which it was initialised. But it might be something else altogether

Comment: Have you considered generating a Vert.x client with vertx-grpc ? See https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-grpc/java/#_stub_api_2 and https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/4.x/grpc-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/grpc/empty/ClientWithStub.java

Answer (score 1):

The block was due to the bigtable client being created in a normal vertical which blocks the event loop when making the call. Moving the instantiation of the client to a worker vertical solved the issue.

[image]

Here the worker vertical should manage the lifecycle of any blocking third party libraries.